# ¿Porque en la consola indica un arreglo de 3 objetos, pero al desplegar su informacion, solo tiene 2 objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo esta situacion: en esta imagen imprimo un arreglo que como verán dice 3 objetos pero al desplegar su información solamente tiene 2 objetos y al momento de recorrerlo efectivamente devuelve la información de 3 objetos.
¿Que podrá ser?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué navegador ves este comportamiento? Está bien extraño

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que te despliega esos datos?

Comment: no agregues el código como imagen así no se puede replicar el ejercicio, pega tu código, seleccionalo y dale clic al ícono `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo posteado por *zerocool* existe una inconsistencia al imprimir en consola objetos (como lo son los arrays) que al momento de imprimirlos, imprime la instancia del objeto pero al momento de explorar ese objeto en consola (darle clic a la flecha para ver las propiedades del objeto) resulta que el explorador va a buscar nuevamente el objeto mostrándote en realidad el estado final del objeto, dicho esto si quieres saber el valor que tenía tu objeto en el momento en que lo imprimiste puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
let persona = { nombre: 'Nombre', edad: 20 };
// imprimir el objeto como string
console.log(JSON.stringify(persona));
// hacer un deep clone del objeto e imprimirlo
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persona)));
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente éste sería un buen workarround. Lo colocaré en la respuesta para que no se pierda entre la explicación que los dos dimos.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó alguna vez con anterioridad y dí con una respuesta en stackoverflow en inglés, te dejo el link:
[inconsistencias en consola de desarrollador](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays)

En el hilo que te indico en el enlace, el usuario Elliot B. explica que teniendo un script en el que tiene un array y que luego es modificado, ejemplo:

```
var greetings=['hi','bye'];
 console.log(greetings);
 setTimeout(function(){
 greetings.push('goodbye');
},3000);
```

Si lo ejecutas y abres la consola de desarrollo verás que se mostrará el array con dos objetos, que sería lo correcto ya que que la instrucción console.log se encuentra antes de la modificación del mismo. Ahora, si ejecutas de nuevo o mejor dicho recargas la página con la consola de desarrollo cerrada y luego de que se termine el script la abres verás en éste caso que se muestra el array con 3 objetos.

En su explicación deja un enlace al jsfiddle de prueba para reproducir el caso:
[jsfiddle reproducir caso inconsistencia consola de desarrollador](http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/kcGkZ/)

El mismo usuario Elliot B. es quien da con la respuesta al encontrar que es un bug notificado para chrome:[Bug 35801 de chrome](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801) en el cual se indica que ha sido cerrado pero por algún motivo todavía no llega a la versión release de éste navegador.

La respuesta es que chrome muestra el estado actual del objeto cuando abres la consola de depuración. Por favor lee la respuesta de LPZadkiel en la que encontrarás una solución a éste error.

Saludos!

Comment: coloca aqui por favor lo relevante de la respuesta en inlgés, pues solo colocar enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Bueno por eso indiqué que es un bug que ha sido cerrado pero no llega a la versión final de chrome.

Comment: pero indicar que es un bug no es una respuesta, traduce la respuesta que te ayudo y colocala aqui y dale referencia al autor original

Comment: ok ya entendí, la edito.